# select few from one table and based on value fetch from another table

Tags: php, laravel

I have three tables:

- `Products`

  - `id`
  - other values
- `Downloads`

  - `id`
  - `user_id`
  - `product_id`
- `Users`

  - `id`
  - `name`

I'd like to fetch last X Download table rows, get their product_id & user_id, product_id match Product table as user_id match User table, then make

```html
foreach ($values as $value) {
    <div class="product_title"> {{$product->name}} </div>
    <div class="who_downloaded"> {{$user->name}} </div>
}
```

I can pass in my controller Download model, but it doesn't get me anywhere close

```php
public function index() {
    return view('nav/index', [
        'trendings' => Template::orderBy('views', 'DESC')->where('is_active', 'yes')->take(8)->get(),
        'latests_downloads' => Downloads::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(8)->get(),
    ]);
}
```

`'latests_downloads' => Downloads::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(8)->get()` function just gives me:

| id | user_id | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 10 |
| 2 | 9 | 2 |
| 3 | 45 | 86 |
| 4 | 88 | 85 |
| 5 | 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 7 | 7 |
| 7 | 5 | 5 |
| 8 | 9 | 6 |

But how can I take these values and put in view?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the following methods to your `Download` model class (If they don't already exist.)

```php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}

public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id');
}
```

2. Change your controller.

```php
'latests_downloads' => Downloads::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(8)->get(),

// replace with the following

'latests_downloads' => Downloads::with(['user', 'product'])->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(8)->get(),
```

3. Fetch it in your view file.

```
@foreach($latest_downloads as $latest_download)

User Id: {{ $latest_download->user->id }}
Product Id: {{ $latest_download->product->id }}

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes for this type of scenario you need to use a relationship-based Eloquent model query of Laravel and it is very powerful for this type of scenario.

First You need to add two relationships in the Download model :

```
public function user()
{
return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}

public function product()
{
return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id');
}
```

And rest of the things work well with this single query.

// user this query

```
$latest_downloads = Downloads::with(['user', 'product'])->latest()->take(8)->get();
```

instead of => getting two different queries in two different variables.

You only need to get a single collection of records in a minimum query and a minimum number of variables. You can do it with Eloquent easily.

And last you can use inside blade as like normal we use daily.

```
@foreach($latest_downloads as $key => $latest_download)
User ID: {{ $latest_download->user->id ?? '' }}
Product ID: {{ $latest_download->product->id ?? '' }}
@endforeach
```